# What is the preferred/popular Vagrant box for Django?

Tags: python, django, vagrant

I am looking for a Vagrant box for Django. I am new to both Vagrant and Django.  Is there a popular/preferred Vagrant box for Django?  With Docker, I can easily answer this question by going to the Docker repository and filtering by stars or download. I can't do that with Vagrant.

I found this: http://devopera.com/applications/django-official-release-python#ubuntu1204  which advertises itself as the official Django box.

I also found: https://github.com/torchbox/vagrant-django-base by Googling "vagrant django".

As a newcomer, is there one I should use? Is there a better box out there?

Answer (score 3):

I would go with https://puphpet.com/ or http://rove.io/

Those are Vagrantfile generator tool. You just highlight what you need and it will be build the Vagrantfile and the provisioner part for you.

You can then just `vagrant up` from the generated file and `ssh` into the box.

I don't think any of the two are installing django so you can install it after you're into the box or add it as an additional provisioner step.

Answer (score 0):

So if you have vagrant and virtual_box installed, then I'd go to [vagrantup.com](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=downloads&provider=&q=django) and download a vagrant box -probably the most downloaded one-. 
Move into that directory, update the .vagrant file if needed, and vagrant up.

Answer (score -1):

Huge fan of [docker-osx](https://github.com/noplay/docker-osx), which can get Docker, Vagrant, and a VM up quickly if you're on a Mac. Install Django. Create your Project/App/Etc. Then build the Docker image, and run the container.

Django on Docker ... up and running in 15 minutes. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was hoping for something as simple as Vagrant add->up->ssh and done. I didn't want to have to install Docker.  Also, It looks I would have to install MySQL with this method.

Answer (score -1):

GitHub has a lot of Vagrant config files, like [this](https://github.com/torchbox/vagrant-django-base) (that I used a couple of times), or more broadly [this](https://github.com/search?q=django%20vagrant).